# Can we have a tag for simple questions for beginners?

Tags: discussion

A good way for beginners to get into code golf is easy challenges. Also, a good way to test and try out a new golfing language is easy challenges. [We](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120925/whats-the-file-extension?answertab=votes#tab-top) [also](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118444/stay-away-from-zero) [have](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/119408/ring-me-when-our-cup-noodles-are-ready) [alot](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/55422/hello-world) [of](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/15417/hello-world-window) [them.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/114544/reciprocal-of-a-number-1-x) I think we should have a [simple](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/simple) or [trivial](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trivial) for that that we can point interested beginners to. It might be nice to have it on the [tour](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/tour). What are your thoughts?

Comment: A [tag:non-trivial] tag would require a lot less retagging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Point them at the search bar, which has a few features that aren't as well known as they could be. In this case, [`answers:20`](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/search?q=answers%3A20) seems like a pretty good way of identifying trivial challenges. And the fact that it gives more than a thousand results seems like a very good argument for not retagging the results.